# How to move windows panels of browser on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, browser-tabs

Please see [image: this screenshot]

I often open Chrome and the incognito windows together (Chrome on left and incognito on right). But sometimes due to my fast speed of clicking, the window shifts from right to left. I can't see how I did it.

Click and drag did not work. How do I shift back to left and right without closing and reopening the window.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you just click and drag it in to position.

Comment: @Appleoddity No, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [7-taskbar-tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)

> Grouping section (in Grouping and Combining pane) > select 'Drag
> within/between groups using right mouse button'

[7-Taskbar-Tweaker.png](https://rammichael.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/7-Taskbar-Tweaker.png)